# Home LAN ping problems

Tags: networking, lan

I've following home LAN structure:

[image]

I'm trying to ping PC2 (192.168.1.2) from PC1 (192.168.0.11) but without success. What should i do to be able to ping it? Should i configure the routing table on PC1?

Comment: Is there a reason to actually have two separate subnets though?

Comment: Why have you got PC1 in that particular location on your LAN? Why not put it behind your router and, if you need to have the PC accessible publicly, then configure port forwards...?

Comment: Had to delete my original comment because I made a mistake. Could you put the models in there of modem and router? Because the real issue here is they are in different subnets. PC1 is in 198.168.0 and PC2 and PC3 are in 192.168.1 . I understand you are using two routers buy why the two subnets im agreeing with @grawity about that. why not just a switch if you need to split them off. Or turn the ISP modem into a bridged one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct, nothing is wrong.

With a typical SoHo NAT router setup, machines on the WAN side of the device cannot ping machines on the LAN side of the device. So machines on the Internet can't ping PC1 because they're on the WAN side of the modem (which is also a router) and PC1 is on the LAN side.

That's how small NAT routers work (like both your router and your modem).

So, similarly, PC1 is on the WAN side of the router because the modem is connected to the router's WAN port. PC2 is on the LAN side of the router. So PC1 should not be able to ping PC2.

If this was not what you wanted, you should not have set your network up this way. If you did this by mistake, change it around. Don't use the router's WAN port, don't set up two LANs, don't set up two DHCP servers, and just make on big happy LAN.

Comment: That's assuming .0.10 is a "typical SoHo NAT router" though.

Comment: @grawity You can always imagine very unusual circumstances the person answering a question might have that might render an answer inapplicable to the person answering the question. You really have no choice but to assume that things not stated are as you'd expect them to be or every answer would be a book detailing every possible circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

On *PC1* you have to configure an static route. On Windows 7 for example it will be:

1. Open the *command prompt* with Administrative rights going to the Start button, then type `cmd` on the search combo box. Right click on the cmd icon and click, Run as administrator
2. Issue the command `route add <destination subnet> mask <destination subnet mask> <gateway>`, in this case:

   **route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.10**

It's a temporary route, to make it permanent you have to use `route add -p`.

Comment: Technically correct, but it would be better to do the same in the "ISP modem" instead, assuming it's configurable enough. That way it'd only need to be done once instead of for every 192.168.0 host...

Comment: Unless he has a very unusual setup, the router will just drop the packet. Otherwise, this would be considered a security vulnerability -- a typical SoHo router in mostly default configuration will typically not let machines on the WAN side of the network choose which LAN devices their packets get forwarded to.

Comment: I've tried solution proposed by jcbermu (adding the route locally on PC1) but no success. When i added the route on the router it works! Can You explain me why does setting the route on the PC1 doesn't works?

Comment: @Mulligan I don't have an explanation. The router should have both routes. There should be no need to add a route if the router is connected to both of them and knows about them.

Comment: @jcbermu What's the difference of adding the route on PC1 vs the router?

Comment: @Mulligan A PC only knows about his own network `(192.168.0.*)`, adding a router and a default gateway is giving him information on how to get to another network beyond its realm. The router, by default **must** have a route for each network he belongs to  `(192.168.0.*)` and  `(192.168.1.*)` according to your diagram. Adding a route to a router let it knows that the networks exists, but it knows because is connected to that network.