# Routing in simple home LAN

Tags: networking, routing

I've following home LAN structure:

[image]

I'm trying to ping PC2 (192.168.1.2) from PC1 (192.168.0.11) but without success. Based on my previous post responses i've added a static route on PC1:

> route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.10

as one responder suggested but still can't ping. What's wrong with it?

---

Can someone please confirm that adding the route locally only on PC1 should be enough because router is in the same net as PC1 (192.168.0.0) and hence can access the gateway 192.168.0.10 directly? Sorry, but i just wont to ensure if i understand the things right.

Comment: What response do you get back when pinging the IP? Have you tried to telnet the device as well? Whats the response from this?

Comment: @Aaron Layfield The response is just "Request timed out". Unfortunately i don't have telnet on my Windows PC1. Can You confirm that adding above route on PC1 should enable the ping?

Comment: This can still be a **duplicate** because you have a previous open post that you could have added the information above. http://superuser.com/questions/1073372/home-lan-ping-problems

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry for possible question duplication but i thought the new one will be better accessible for community

Answer (score 0):

Ping is a two-way street. If the machine cannot get a response, it fails. Can you ping from PC2 to PC1?

A firewall can also be blocking the ping. Some firewalls will not respond to ICMP as well.

Comment: Yes i can ping PC2 from PC1. I've also checked that Win firewall is off. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Does the router have a route set for the other subnet?

Comment: The router has the following route: "192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1" - is it right?

Comment: You might have better luck if you stick them all on the same subnet. Your secondary router may support DHCP-FORWARD or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your net mask to 255.255.0.0 (static WAN on your router.)
... and make sure you do not have **Block ICMP Ping** activated on your router.

Aside from that you could connect the LAN side of your modem to the LAN side of your router, disable the router's DHCP, statically assign IP address', netmasks, Gateway and DNS on each of your router's clients ... unless you intentionally want them to be behind the second firewall in your router.

The gateway and first DNS setting on your clients would be that of the Modem: 192.168.0.1

---

**OTHER OPTIONS**

*If your router is compatible* check into flashing your firmware with dd-wrt or tomato to convert it into a much better router... 
["Turn your $60 router into a $600 router"](http://lifehacker.com/178132/hack-attack-turn-your-60-router-into-a-600-router)

[www.dd-wrt.com | Unleash Your Router](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index)

[Tomato Firmware | polarcloud.com](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato)

Or if you have a spare PC lying around and you really want a profesional grade Router you can add some NIC cards or a Multi-port NIC card and give the Community Version of pfSense a go:

[Download pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/download/)

pfSense is what I use in an old Dell Latitude D610 laptop as a wireless client / bridge router to a WiFi ISP Modem in a similar setup to yours.
I also have both dd-wrt and Tomato in 2 other routers (Linksys WRT54GL) inline to the Dell running pfSense on top of a 80 port Hewlett Packard ProCurve Switch 4000M in the mix.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup a route on the Modem to go to the 192.168.1.0 network.

You just have to setup the routes on the modem and the router as the PCs gateway are (I assume) set to the modem/router. No need to set up routes on the PCs as long as you have a default gateway pointing to modem/router and having the routes set up there. The PC will send all traffic sent outside its network to the DG and there the route has to be set up.

Of course the firewall has to be allowing the traffic, but I think you should be fine if they are "standard" modems/routers which have a firewall between WAN and LAN connection.

A thumb of rule is to have all routes setup from point a to point b on all the crossroads - both ways!

Comment: Why should i setup routes on the modem & router if PC1 & router is in the same net - both in 192.168.0.0 and i can ping 192.168.0.10 (router WAN) successfully?

Comment: Can You please answer my question?

Comment: Sorry, was not at my computer. For your situation I think you are fine with just setting it up on the PC (should work). I was thinking ahead and my solution would be the nice way for every device in the 192.168.0.x network. Further I think you could check with a traceroute from both sides to see where the packets go and where it is stuck. And I would test the ping to both router IP addresses from both networks as this could show you where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons:

- Most (non-crappy) routers will block incoming pings unless you enable it in the settings (if possible), as a security feature.
- It looks like you have NAT set up on the second router.  Unless you set up port forwarding rules or a DMZ, incoming traffic will not be forwarded to any system behind the router.

  - There's a good chance your router will only let you setup forwarding rules for TCP or UDP, but not ICMP as required by ping.  Google can lead you to any number of simple web servers you can run on a Windows system to test on HTTP port 80.

Comment: There are no ports in ICMP, so that's to be expected. 